# Javascript - How to pass data from table into select options in modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Sorry for my bad english before. I have already pass data to a modal bootstrap. and already have successed passing data to an **input** in modal. but i dont know how to pass into a **select option** in modal.

how to do that? and displaying in select option with data.

Thanks in advance

here some of my code:

**Get data from table:**

```
<a href="javascript:;"
    data-id="<?php echo $s1['sub_menuid']?>"
    data-mainid="<?php echo $s1['main_menuid']?>"
    data-nama="<?php echo $s1['nama_submenu']?>"
    data-link="<?php echo $s1['link']?>"
    data-icon="<?php echo $s1['icon']?>"
    class="green" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-edit" data-rel="tooltip" title="Edit">
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil bigger-130"></i>
    </a>
```

**passing into modal via javascript**

```
$('#modal-edit').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
             var div = $(event.relatedTarget) // Tombol dimana modal di tampilkan
             var modal          = $(this)

             // Isi nilai pada field
             modal.find('#sub_menuid').attr("value",div.data('id'));
             modal.find('#main_menuid').attr("value",div.data('mainid'));
             modal.find('#nama_submenu').attr("value",div.data('nama'));
             modal.find('#link').attr("value",div.data('link'));
             /*modal.find('#icon').attr("value",div.data('icon'));*/
         });
```

**modal-edit:**

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal-edit" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><b>Edit Sub Menu Level 1</b></h4>
                </div>
                <form class="form-horizontal" id="form-edit" action="<?php echo base_url('sub_menu_level_1/edit')?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-2 control-label">Nama Sub Menu</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="hidden" id="sub_menuid" name="sub_menuid">
                                <input type="text" id="nama_submenu" class="form-control" name="nama_submenu" placeholder="Nama menu">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-2 control-label">Pilih Main Menu</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <select class="form-control" id="main_menuid" name="main_menuid">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <?php foreach($main_menu as $mm) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $mm['main_menuid']?>"><?php echo ucwords($mm['nama_mainmenu'])?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-2 control-label">Link</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" id="link" class="form-control" name="link" placeholder="link">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"> Batal</button>
                        <button id="btn-submit-edit" class="btn btn-info" type="submit"> Simpan&nbsp;</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END Modal edit -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
modal.find("#main_menuid").val(div.data('mainid'));
```

here's a sample.

```js
$('#modal-edit').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
             var div = $(event.relatedTarget) // Tombol dimana modal di tampilkan
             var modal          = $(this)

             // Isi nilai pada field
             modal.find('#sub_menuid').attr("value",div.data('id'));
             modal.find("#main_menuid").val(div.data('mainid'));
             modal.find('#nama_submenu').attr("value",div.data('nama'));
             modal.find('#link').attr("value",div.data('link'));
             /*modal.find('#icon').attr("value",div.data('icon'));*/
         });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:;"
    data-id="1"
    data-mainid="3"
    data-nama="abcd"
    data-link="abcd"
    data-icon="abcd"
    class="green" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-edit" data-rel="tooltip" title="Edit">
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil bigger-130"></i>click me
    </a>
    
    
    <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal-edit" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><b>Edit Sub Menu Level 1</b></h4>
                </div>
                <form class="form-horizontal" id="form-edit" action="<?php echo base_url('sub_menu_level_1/edit')?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-2 control-label">Nama Sub Menu</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="hidden" id="sub_menuid" name="sub_menuid">
                                <input type="text" id="nama_submenu" class="form-control" name="nama_submenu" placeholder="Nama menu">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-2 control-label">Pilih Main Menu</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <select class="form-control" id="main_menuid" name="main_menuid">
                                <option value="1">val1</option>
                                
                                <option value="2">val2</option>
                                <option value="3">val3</option>
                               
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-2 control-label">Link</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" id="link" class="form-control" name="link" placeholder="link">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"> Batal</button>
                        <button id="btn-submit-edit" class="btn btn-info" type="submit"> Simpan&nbsp;</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```